# Unable to connect to mongodb via express project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Tracing the documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html) and failing to load bson apparently. After running `npm start` I receive:

[image]

Snippet:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

//connect to db server
mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:28017/myDb", function(err, db){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to Database")
    }
    else{
        console.log("failed to connect");
    }
});
```

I have tried updating/reinstalling the driver modules as well. Totally new to the framework & db and this type of error feels so trivial that it is discouraging that I am unable to figure it out. Help!

Comment: Failing to load the c++ bson extension doesn't mean it failed, it should still print "connented to database" or "failed to connect", does it do that?

Comment: prints "failed to connect"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default port for mongodb is 27017 (and then 28017 is for a web status page).
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/

Try this connect string:
"mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb"

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it and I am now able to connect to the backend. However, the "failed to load..." message still remains. What is this and should it be a pause of concern?

Comment: It's using the JavaScript version of the BSON extension, instead of the C++ version. It's presumably slower, but should be fine for development. For a production environment you really should get the C++ version installed. That might be as simple as reinstalling the mongodb module, which should compile the C++ version. I've seen this warning when the mongodb module was build on one OS, and then just copied to another OS - for example, installed on a Mac development machine and then copied to Linux.